# Windows 10 - can't change bluetooth headphone volume with buttons on headphones

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, headphones

Sorry if this is the wrong place for this.

I started having this problem with my Windows 10 laptop and my bluetooth headphones (I'm sure it's the computer because the feature I'm having trouble with works fine on my phone with both pairs of bluetooth headphones I own). When I try to use the volume buttons on the headphones to change the volume, it doesn't work; I can only use the slider at the bottom right of the screen, which is very inconvenient for me. In the past when I clicked the button, I could change the volume while a video or sound file was playing, and if one wasn't the volume icon would still pop up but not move. Now, neither is working. Is there a way to fix this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If you previously could control the volume from the headphones, this problem might be due to a Windows Update.

Please see this Microsoft article about the issue, especially under "If your Bluetooth volume controls no longer work after you install a Windows update, follow these steps.", here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-bluetooth-problems-in-windows-10-723e092f-03fa-858b-5c80-131ec3fba75c

Instructions copied below, in case the link stops working:

1. Make sure you've installed the latest updates from Windows Update. (A solution for this issue was included in the [October 24, 2018—KB4462933 (OS Build 17134.376)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/october-24-2018-kb4462933-os-build-17134-376-0e005f56-5b85-868e-9362-970c62d58d50) update for Windows 10 version 1803.)
   To check for updates, select Start , and then go to Settings  > Update & security  > Windows Update  > Check for updates.
2. Manually disable the Absolute Volume feature by making a change in the registry. To do this, select Start  and type cmd. Right-click Command Prompt in the Search results and select Run as administrator.
3. In the Command Prompt window, type the following command:

`reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT /v DisableAbsoluteVolume /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`

You may need to restart Windows for the registry change to take effect.